# Multiple Node.js Apps on one server using passport & oauth

Tags: node.js, session, oauth, passport.js

I have several apps with node.js & passport using oauth (openstreetmap oauth).

e.g.

`domain.com/app1
domain.com/app2`

There is a proxy distributing the requests to each app.

I have tried to use the same secret & key in both apps, but as soon as I open one app, I have to login again.

I store the session with connect-pg-simple.

What could be an approach to use the oauth login and "session" from both app? Of course both apps needs the sessions to store additional data.

Would it be a solution to have a shared session table (every app has his own postgres database) ? but i assume this can result in merging data problems, when both apps want to update the store ?

My idea is to provide several small node.js / postgres apps, not depending on each other, but using the same comfortable oauth login.

Comment: You can share the database connexion and use the same tables. There will be no issue if two apps are trying to update the store at the same time, Postgres and other databases are good at that.

Comment: connection-pg-simple is storing session data as JSON in one field, so my fear is, that it will overwrite its values, if the data is used in parallel.
But i will try.

Comment: one field for each session or one field for all sessions? It would be surprising that it creates only one field for all of the sessions storage. After a quick look at the module code it also appear that it opens a connexion for each query, you should consider using something else

Comment: https://github.com/voxpelli/node-connect-pg-simple/blob/master/index.js#L137